# Working on page flow in responsiveness using css and images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on the below reference image work on responsiveness using css media query and images. I am trying to avoid position I am not getting the excact output which I required.

Here is my [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/derf3bbc/)

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="flw_width">
            <label class="pull-left flw_text green_prog_text">Basic Information</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-1">
                <div class="flw_circle_green">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="green_prog">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>  
            <label class="pull-left flw_text cst_text">Education &amp; Health</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-1">
                <div class="flw_circle_grey">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="grey_prog">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <label class="pull-left flw_text cst_text">Attach &amp; Declaration</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-1">
                <div class="flw_circle_grey">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="grey_prog">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <label class="pull-left flw_text pay_text">Payment</label>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-1">
                <div class="flw_circle_grey">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code

```
.flw_width{
   width: 480px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding-top:45px;
   padding-bottom: 60px;
 }
 .flw_text{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ced3d0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-left: -45px;
    border:0px;
  }

    .flw_text, .cst_text{
    margin-left: -46px !important;
}
.pay_text{
    padding-left:26px;
}
.flw_circle_grey{
    background: url(../images/grey_Circle.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
.flw_circle_green{
    background: url(../images/green_Circle.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.grey_prog{
    background-color: #ced3d0;
    height: 6px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
}
.green_prog_text{
    color: #84bd00;
}
.green_prog{
    background-color: #84bd00;
    height: 6px;
    margin-left: -24px;

}
```

My current output was like this.

[image: Current Output]

Here is the reference image.  Kindly help me I was struggling like anything.

Please do the needful.

[image: Expectated output]

Answer (score 1):

You have selected the column grid wrongly, I think For the class which are representing the font awesome circle (green dot) `fa fa-circle flw_circle_green` can be changed to single grid where you have defined a 4 column grid.

Try updating the four column grid to one column 1 column and use the

Comment: Thanks for your comment but (Desktop screen) I have used column 1 for green circle and prog  column3